# SwiftUI List initializer with identified(by:)

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm working through Apple's SwiftUI tutorial on [building lists and navigation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#make-the-list-dynamic), and I can't seem to find any documentation for this `List` initializer, or the `identified(by:)` method of the `Array` type:

```swift
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(landmarkData.identified(by: \.id)) { landmark in

        }
    }
}
```

When I right-click on the `List` initializer and click `Jump to Definition` in Xcode, it takes me to [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/3270228-init) which isn't right. When I do the same for the `identified(by:)` method, it takes me to this strange file, which only has 13 lines and no mention of the `identified(by:)` method:

[image]

I know Xcode is in beta, but where can I find the documentation for these mysterious bits of code? The tutorial has been great up to this point, but I'm not certain what this `List` and `Array` are doing.

Comment: They are **function builders** introduced in swift 5.1, what do you really want to know?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3298105-identified, the List initializer is the one that takes a `() -> Content` closure.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks, I couldn't find that `identified(by:)` method anywhere. As for the `List` initializer, why doesn't it require me to specify the `content` parameter name? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/3270227-init

Comment: @RobJohansen Maybe I am mistaken. Try to write explicit `.init` and jump to that.

Answer (score 6):

`identified` is no more in use now. You may try below syntax.

```
List{
    ForEach(landmarkData, id: \.id) { landmark in
       Text(landmark.placeName)
    }
}
```