# SwiftUI Bug Fix "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<int>'to expected type 'Binding<_>?'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm having trouble with this error :

> "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding'to expected type 'Binding<_>?'"

I think I'm coding in an out dated version of SwiftUI but I'm not 100% sure, so any help I can get will be awesome.

I displayed my code down below so you can take a look at it.

I'm not sure if the bottom part matters but I added it just to be safe.

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){

            NavigationView{
            Text("First View")
                .font(.title)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Welcome"))
                }
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        Text("Welcome")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            NavigationView{

                List(networkManager.featureList.results.identified(by: \.url)) { featured in
                Text(featured.name.capitalized)
                }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
                }
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "app.badge.fill")
                        Text("Featured")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
            NavigationView{
            Text("First View")
                .font(.title)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Repos"))
                }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.stack.fill")
                    Text("Repos")
                }
            }
            .tag(2)
            NavigationView{
            Text("First View")
                .font(.title)
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Request"))
                }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down.fill")
                    Text("Request")
                }
            }
            .tag(3)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**ApiView**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()
    var featureList = FeaturedApiList(results: []){
        didSet{
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/repos.json") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let featureList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(FeaturedApiList.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.featureList = featureList

            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error shown is very confusing, but some other errors would cause this sort of error.

In your case, you may need to fix the second `NavigationView` in the `TabView`:

```
            NavigationView{
                //↓Fix this line.
                List(networkManager.featureList.results, id: \.url) { featured in
                    Text(featured.name.capitalized)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "app.badge.fill")
                    Text("Featured")
                }
            }
            .tag(1)
```

Better check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57020555/6541007) and always try to find an up-to-date samples or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

OOPer is actually correct. You will need to fix your `List`.
Let's try to replace your data for the `List` just to see that the project will compile:

Suppose we have a model that conforms to `Identifiable` protocol, like so:

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

And then replace your `List` line with this:

```
List([Person(name: "fafa")]) { featured in
    Text(featured.name)
}
```

This time it should run. Since SwiftUI is new, this must be the reason why the error is quite confusing.